# Vector fields and first integrals of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble understanding following theory. Starting from an ordinary differential equation: $$ \frac{dx_i}{dt}=X_i(x) \qquad (i=1,..,n)$$ we can associate this ODE with following vector field. $$X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} $$ Now we have following proposition. A function $f(x)$ is a first integral of our ODE if and only if $X(f)=0$. I think it's a quite simple fact but i don't see why.

A function $f(x)$ is said to be a first integral of our ODE if for every solution $x(t)$ of our ODE f(x(t)) is constant.

Comment: How would you define a first integral of an ODE?

Answer (score 2):

If the derivative of f along trajectories of the vector field is 0, then it is a first integral. In your case, this means

$\frac{df(x(t))}{dt}=\vec\nabla f(x(t)).\vec X(x(t))=0$, which is what you have written.